# C++ process management: WinAPI "SetProcessShutdownParameters " in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, process

In Windows (7), in VC++ we can set the "process shutdown parameters" (in XP a parent process will automatically shutdown before the child) to ensure a parent process is killed BEFORE a child process, like so:

```
GetProcessShutdownParameters(&shutdownlevel, &shutdownflags);
SetProcessShutdownParameters(shutdownlevel+1, SHUTDOWN_NORETRY);
```

How to do this in C++ on Linux (gcc) ? I find a lot discussion in many forums on how to ensure a child process killed, in case a parent process dies (e.g. use of prctl on Linux), but I have found nothing on how to GUARANTEE that the parent process is killed by the OS before the child process, like the above for Windows. Maybe it is automatic in Linux ?

Comment: I don't think there's any system facility for that. And honestly, I'm curious as to why you need the parent process to die before the child: I can't find any reason on my own. Care to share? Typically you'll want your parent to monitor the child, and take an action (exit) when it detects the child has died, but of course that means the parent exits *after* the child.

Answer (score 0):

System shutdown in the Unix world works a bit differently.

When the system is being shut down, at first the shutdown scripts are invoked, which handle any complex or time consuming tasks, and when the scripts have run, all remaining processes are then first sent a `SIGTERM` signal (which kills any process that doesn't have an explicit handler), and, a few seconds later, a `SIGKILL` signal (which kills the process and cannot be handled).

The order in which the last part happens is undefined.

In general programs should be written so they can be shutdown by simply sending `SIGTERM`.

I'm guessing that you want the parent stopped before the child because the parent would simply restart the child. The proper way to avoid that is to collect the child's exit status (which you are responsible for anyway), and avoid restarting when the exit status indicates that the process ended because of being sent `SIGTERM`.

(You still want to restart on `SIGKILL`, because that is what happens to the largest process when the system runs out of memory)

Comment: I need the OS to send the "kill" signal first to the parent because I need to ensure that the child processes are NOT killed randomly by the OS but will be killed by the parent process (that means cleanup, etc will be done).
                                                                                           But when I check the processes running before issuing a shutdown command and right when the first script executes from RL 0/ 6, it seems that some processes are are already killed BEFORE the OS moves to executes the scripts in /etc/init.d . Any idea when and why ?

Comment: The processes killed before the shutdown scripts are run are those that are started directly from init, i.e. those listed in the `inittab`.

Comment: The child processes should not depend on the parent for cleanup, simple as that. Processes die for reasons other than system shutdown, and even in this case, the system should behave in the best way it can.

Comment: "Child processes should not depend on the parent for cleanup": fully agreed. Unfortunately, there are sometimes bigger (corporate) forces than us smart individuals. So I cannot change this.                          I ran my own application and verified with ps - command whether it was running. I noticed that it was killed BEFORE the first script in RL 0 got executed (I added this check into the first script being executed and my application was already killed). Any idea why ? That is the fact I cannot understand.

Comment: Like you mention, I also thought user applications would be killed by the SIGTERM signal (sent to all processes), AFTER system scripts are getting executed. But this seems not the case.... or I am misunderstanding something. Also processes running in a shell seem to get killed first. So the basic sequence is: 1) shutdown processes in inittab, 2) execute scripts in RL 0 ? I read this link but the problem is still not solved: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-lpic1-v3-101-3/ Thanks for your help.

Comment: `init` is fairly agnostic about the meanings of the runlevels, and it doesn't know that the scripts start and stop services. From its point of view, it should kill any process it started that belongs to another runlevel, run the "once" processes for the new runlevel first, and then start all the "restart" and "nowait" processes (unless they were already running in the old runlevel).

Comment: So if your master process is killed first, that sounds like it is started from the `inittab`.